# Как для scale задать опцию tab1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

столкнулся с проблемой что для scale нельзя поставить опцию tab1, например

```
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)  
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control) 
tab_control.add(tab1, text='TEST1')  
tab_control.add(tab2, text='TEST2')
lbl1 = Label(tab1, text='TEST1')  
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
scale = tk.Scale(tab1, root, from_=0, to=100, command=on_scroll1, orient="horizontal", label="TEST")
scale.place(x=5, y=77)
lbl2 = Label(tab2, text='TEST2')  
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=0)
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
tab_control.place(x=0, y=30)
```

данный код выдает ошибку: scale не находит опцию `tab1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым позиционным параметром передают родительский элемент управления, к которому привязывается данный виджет.
Просто определитесь, вы к `root` привязываете или к `tab1`. Если к `tab1`, то уберите `root` из параметров:

```
scale = tk.Scale(tab1, from_=0, to=100, command=on_scroll1, orient="horizontal", label="TEST")
```

Comment: Теперь они вообще пропали

Comment: @Selasi попробуйте поменять place на grid или pack. Возможно у вас другие виджеты на шкалу наложились.

Comment: Ну тогда создавайте шкалу последней, чтобы она была поверх всего. А вообще вам скорее всего нужны не определенные координаты, а отступы, а это настраивается и через grid, и через pack.

Comment: она и так в конце

Comment: Тогда уберите `tab_control.place(x=0, y=30)`, оставьте только `tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')`, тогда таб будет расширяться при расширении окна. Если нужен отступ, добавьте отступ через опции pack, например `tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=30, pady=30)`.

Comment: Я кстати заметил что для Scale нельзя поставить grid

Comment: @Selasi ошибаетесь, для Scale можно поставить grid.

Comment: А да действительно, я просто допустил небольшую ошибку в коде